# Efficient computation of the sum of all pairwise distances of a set of points, all on a finite 2D grid

Tags: algorithm, 2d, euclidean-distance

Given a set of `n` points in `2D` plane. We need to find sum of euclidean distance between every point to every other points i.e. `ΣΣdist(P(i)P(j))` for `i:[1,n-1]`, `j:[i+1,n]`. It is also given that for every point `P(xi,yi)` : `1<=xi<=500` and  `1<=yi<=500`. I know this can be done in O(n^2). But want to know if it can be done more efficiently. Any help on how to further optimize it.

Comment: Are the coordinates of these points integer values?

Comment: If the points are integers, then it can be done in O(n) time.

Comment: @v78 yes the points are integer values only.

Comment: If you want for squared distances you can do it in O(n) by using the fact that the sum of squared distances in a clique divided by n is the sum of squared distances to the center of mass, for the case of distances and not squared distances you can get a number which is at most 1+epsilon and at least 1-epsilon multiplied by the correct result in time O(n*log(1/delta)/epsilon^2) where delta is the probability of failure, you can do this by building an epsilon-coreset, I can explain more if you're still interested in this question.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know any way to do better than `O(n^2)` if the coordinates are arbitrary, but in your case you could use the following remark:

If `1<=xi<=500` and `1<=yi<=500`, and are integer values, there are at most `250000` distinct points.

So in the case of a large number of points, you could count how many distinct points there actually are (which is bounded), and how many times each of them appears (consider a hashmap for this). Once this is done, you have a set of distinct points `P(i)`, and you know `m(i)`, the number of times `P(i)` appeared in your original set, and you can compute the quantity you want as follows: `ΣΣm(i)m(j)dist(P(i)P(j))`. The complexity is just `O(n)` now, to read the input.

The constant hidden in the `O(n)` notation is big, however. If instead of `500` you said that `xi` and `yi` are bounded by a non-fixed `k`, what I am pointing out is just that the complexity is `O(min(n^2,n+k^2))`

If you only need an approximation, then there might be other things that you can do. (random sampling, partitioning close points into clusters ...)

Comment: I could see that it is very obvious to keep the count of the distinct points and multiplying it with distance. But the thing is that in the worst case there are 25*10^4 unique points. And than again I have to calculate the distance between every unique point to other points. So total ~6.25*10^10 operations, which is quite large no of operations.

Comment: Could an approximation be enough then ? Or a lower bound, an upper bound, or both ?

Comment: @Roshan For example, if you partition your points into a coarser `g*g` grid, computing a center of mass for each cell of the grid, and using that as your new points, you are distorting each individual original distance by at most `(sqrt(2)*k/g)` (where `k=500` is the size of the original grid) which could be fine, depending of the context.

Comment: what do u mean by approximation ?. is it equal to saying that we should consider floor(distance) or ceil (distance) instead the floating value of distance.

Comment: @Roshan I mean computing a quantity that might be further from the exact theoretical result but at a lower cost. If you use floats and compute the algorithm as first suggested, you should get a result that is off by a `2^-27` fraction of the true value. What I'm saying is that you could use another, faster, algorithm, that gives a result that is not as close to the theoretical value. (for example, by merging together the points `{(2*i,2*i), (2*i+1,2*i),(2*i,2*i+1),(2*i+1,2*i+1)}` into the point `(2*i+0.5,2*i+0.5)`(or the center of mass), summing multiplicities. That should divide time by ~4).

Comment: Would not this hypothesis be helpful when I am going to consider the floor value of distance calculate between every point instead of the actual distance value.

Comment: What I am thinking is to map every points to some special points and then compute the pairwise distance sum on those specials points only. And keep multiplying the counts of points mapped at every pair of specials points.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138841/discussion-between-a-n-and-roshan).